# HashMap of hashMap

Tags: java

I've this content :

> lithium hydride : Li 1 H 1 #comment...

and I want the following result :

> {lithium hydride’ : {’Li’ : 1, ’H’ : 1},...}

I do that :

```
public static HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>> readFormulas(String content){
    HashMap<String,Integer> dictionnaire1 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>> dictionnaire2 = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>>();
        ArrayList <String>  al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add(Arrays.toString(content.split(":")));// on met chaque ligne dans un tableau
        String str[] = content.split("\n");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length;i++){//pour chaque ligne 
            String str2 [] = str[i].split(":");// séparer les noms des molécules des noms scientiques et des  commentaires ["Helium","he 1 #fzefzezfezfz"
            String NomMolecule = str2[0];
            String diese [] = str2[1].split("#");
            String description [] = diese[0].split(" ");
            int nb = Integer.parseInt(description[2]);
            dictionnaire1.put(description[1], nb);
            }
            dictionnaire2.put(NomMolecule,dictionnaire1);
        }
      return(dictionnaire2);
     }
```

But the result is bad , I don't understand why ?? : 
Entries:

```
 HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>> formulas = readFormulas("helium : he 3 #fsdfsfsdfsf" + "\n" + "lithium hydride : Li 1 H 1 #fdvdfdfvd");
```

result :

> {lithium hydride ={he=3, Li=1}, helium ={he=3, Li=1}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one HashMap for each molecule:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length;i++){//pour chaque ligne 
    String str2 [] = str[i].split(":");
    String NomMolecule = str2[0];
    String diese [] = str2[1].split("#");
    String description [] = diese[0].trim().split(" ");
    HashMap<String,Integer> dictionnaire1 = new HashMap<>();
    for( int j = 0; j < description.length; j += 2 ){
        int nb = Integer.parseInt(description[j+1]);
        dictionnaire1.put(description[j], nb);
    }
    dictionnaire2.put(NomMolecule,dictionnaire1);
}
```

You are also missing a loop over the constituents (e.g. Li 1 H 1) of a molecule, which I have added.

Comment: thank's a lot laune :). But I don't understand  this : why j+=2

Comment: One for "Li" and one for "1" makes 2. Then, one for "H" and one for "1" makes 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<String,Integer> dictionnaire1 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

As this `HashMap` is reused on each loop iteration, previous(stale) elements of map makes wrong output.

Explanation :

In first iteration dictionnaire1 : `{he:3}`

In Second iteration, same map is reused with earlier filed data.

Data item found - `{Li: 1}` & `{he:3}`

That is how, you got the result. `{Li: 1,he:3}`

---

To get the desired result :
**First** you need to clear all previous entry of `dictionnaire1`, on each iteration.

**Second** you need tweak the logic a bit of retrieving multiple element from  `description` array -

```
for(int j=1;j<description.length-1;j+=2){
    int nb = Integer.parseInt(description[j+1]);
    dictionnaire1.put(description[j], nb);
}
```